# Back Stack in fragments using Tabs in Action Bar in Android

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am developing an application which have following requirements:

1) App has few tabs and each tab has multiple activities.
2) There should be proper back navigation to make the application user friendly.

For this, I used action bar and tabs in my application.

[image]

Tabs has multiple screens (Requirement).

```
    Tab 1: Fragment A --> Fragment B ---> Fragment C

    Tab 2: Fragment P --> Fragment Q ---> Fragment R

    Tab 3: Fragment X --> Fragment Y ---> Fragment Z
```

Now I want to use the back functionality from each fragment So the user comeback from next fragment to previous fragment in each tab like:

```
  Fragment c --> Fragment B ---> Fragment A
```

**I want that user can use back button of device and We can use custom button in action bar  for the back navigation.**

**I also want to change the title of action bar according to the current fragment.**

How can I implement this? Any other better approach which can be used in this situation.'

Please reply. I am not getting solution for this type of situations.

Thanks a lot.

Please provide me solution or best approach for this. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example, it should do what you want.

https://gist.github.com/andreynovikov/4619215